# C# -- поиск элемента со значением value

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Есть код, написанный на PhantomJS driver:

```
var element2 = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("input"));
tadress.Text = (element2).Text;
```

В переменную `element2` не записывается текст из элемента с тэгом `"input"` по двум причинам:

1. Не указан массив [0].
2. Элемент содержит информацию не формате `.Text` или `.innerText`,а в формате `value`.
   Как можно исправить код, чтобы устранить обе проблемы?

Comment: а где код который нужно исправить?добавьте то что уже напсали

Comment: `element2.getAttribute("value");` надо тогда